Validity passport non-EU person with Schengen residence
My wife and I are going from Belgium to Italy by plane for a week in June. I am a Belgian citizen, my wife is Asian.
She has EU (Belgium) residence through our marriage, and traveling inside Schengen with the plane has never been a problem for us.
She does have to show her Belgian residence/ID card AND her passport of her country before boarding the plane.
I noticed now that her passport will expire in October this year, and I was wondering how much validity should she have left on her passport. Her Belgian residence/ID card by the way will expire in December of this year.
Are we good to go or can any of the above cause a problem?

If you travel on a full cost (aka not Ryanair or Wizz air, etc) chances are no one would inspect your documents.


My wife and I are going from Belgium to Italy by plane for a week in June.
... how much validity should she have left on her passport.

As a spouse of an EU Citizen, the conditions of the Freedom of Movement, when both are traveling togeather, apply.
The passport must be valid for the duration of the time outside the country of residence (Article 6 (2)).
With a passport, which expires in October, a trip in June will be no problem.


DIRECTIVE 2004/38/EC (Freedom of Movement)
Article 6
Right of residence for up to three months

Union citizens shall have the right of residence on the territory of another Member State for a period of up to three months without any conditions or any formalities other than the requirement to hold a valid identity card or passport.
The provisions of paragraph 1 shall also apply to family members in possession of a valid passport who are not nationals of a Member State, accompanying or joining the Union citizen.


